# How to install a window ac in a room with improper window provision

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a window ac that I used it earlier. Recently shifted my premises and my bed room has a window with two wood doors that open oppositely and a lengthy wood stick in the middle. Window is safeguarded with iron fittings on either sides of middle wood stick and this is making unsuitable for my ac installation. My owners are not permitting to cut the middle wood stick. Added to this iron gauze is also should be cut for installation. Are there any alternate procedure for installation . Can I keep my window ac completely out side the window

Comment: A photo or two might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the circumstances you may be facing having to shift your premises back to the previously workable configuration!!

On another track you could consider using a different type of portable A/C unit altogether. There are available floor standing units that vent out through a large flexible hose to a window. There is typically an adjustable panel assembly that can be fitted to the window (see below). Note that there are also styles of these that use two of the flexible hoses.

[image]